# PHP Is there an equivalent to npm link for composer?

Tags: php, npm, composer-php, dependency-management, npm-link

When I am developing a JavaScript module, I can use [npm link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) to install my local development version in local projects that use the module as a dependency. This is a great workflow.

It's not developing in place, which I think is a less good than TDD, but its a way easier way to do integration testing and manual QA, I think.

In Composer, I can, if possible, force a package to install using git, so then I can develop in place. Nice, but not great.

Short version of question: Can I tell composer to temporarily install a dependency from a git repo/ set of files in my local file system and control the link from the composer CLI?

Comment: No there is not, but take a look at this https://github.com/franzliedke/studio. There is a discussion on github about this feature in the composer repository.

Comment: Here it is: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/601

Answer (score 5):

You could use a [path repo](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) in your `composer.json`.

This will install a symlink instead of a git clone in your vendor folder.

This is exactly what already mentioned `franzl/studio` package does under the hood.

Answer (score 1):

I created my own plugin for this

https://github.com/SanderSander/composer-link

It doesn't alter your composer.json or lock file.